# Setting the date in an HTML5 date input

Tags: html, datepicker

I'm trying to progamatically set the date in an HTML5 date input using ajax and javascript. I have an ajax/php call that returns the date that I want in a string variable in the format "YYYY-MM-DD". I can't seem to make this work. Here is my attempt:

```
var myDate = "2013-07-10" //actually is returned by my ajax call, but same idea

//set the date value
var thisDate = new Date();
thisDate.setFullYear(parseInt(workout_date.split("-")[0]));
thisDate.setMonth(parseInt(workout_date.split("-")[1])-1);
thisDate.setDate(parseInt(workout_date.split("-")[2]));

document.getElementById("date_input").value = thisDate;
```

I'm not getting any errors, but my date input just remains at the default (mm/dd/yyyy). Anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to set the value of the date to a Date object. But the [date input](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#date-state-%28type=date%29), like other inputs, can only accept strings:

> If the user agent provides a user interface for selecting a date, then the value must be set to a valid date **string** representing the user's selection. [Emphasis added.]

In this case, `myDate` represents a valid date string, so you can use it directly.

Comment: I swear that I had tried that, but didn't get it to work, which is why I went down the `new Date()` path. But it works now. Thanks!